# How to solve the issue in array search

Tags: php, arrays

I am doing a site for publishing ads, in a section of adding the campaign (ads) I need to prevent certain badwords from the campaign title. So I have checked those title when the advertiser adds the campaign. These badwords are stored in a file in txt format. I have used this code.

```
$string = $description;

$badwords = file( "badwords.txt" );
if ( $badwords ) { 
  foreach ( $badwords as $line ) {  
    if ( preg_match("/$line/", $string) ) { 
      echo $string; die();
      return array ( 0, $language['bad_words_error'] );
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried `in_array()` but i can't match the content in `$string`.

```
if ( in_array($string, $badwords) ) { 
  echo "The word ".$string ." is a bad keyword"; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? (Echoing both lines and seeing if it really matches?) Also, try `trim()`ming your lines.

Comment: @Truth Thanks it works. I used the trim() before checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the problem comes from trailing spaces left in the file.

To solve this, use `trim()` on individual `$line`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($badwords as $word) {
  if (preg_match("/\b$word\b/", $string)) {
    echo $string . ' contains bad word ' . $value;
  }
}
```

I am assuming your txt file contains one bad word per line. Also be careful your badwords don't include characters which may corrupt regular expression pattern.